# Affiliate Marketing Link Auto-fill

Tags: wordpress, affiliate

I'm building a website in which folks register for services to make passive income.  Additionally, these services offer referral bonuses.

The default setting is to have my personal referral links.  I have icons displayed that have URLs for my referral bonus.

I'd love for users to be able to create an account on the website and have it generate a referral URL.  When they share it, I want the page to be identical to the original, but the icons to now have their referral links.

I can create a wordpress site that has users log in.  I can also assign them a generic identifier.  I can also create a submission form that stores their specific referral URLs in the userdata of the website.

What I can't do is automatically change the icon URLs to match their referral links.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that automatically changing hyperlinks to icons is a database task.  Also, dynamic pages on Wix will allow custom user URL's.

However, the most effective method of this is to have an affiliate system and pay for it.